# Python: zip extraction with more than 255 characters strings

Tags: python, character

I try to execute this code in Python:

```
os.mkdir(out_dir)
with zipfile.ZipFile(APP_NAME, "r") as z:
    z.extractall(out_dir)
    files=z.namelist()
return files,out_dir
```

but if the characters of **out_dir** is >255 it goes into error. Is there a way to handle it?

Comment: you mean >255, right ?

Comment: Oh yes! I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a limitation of the underlying [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits). Most of then, including extN or NTFS have a limit of 255 chars in filenames.

You could limit the size of the name with `out_dir[:255]` but then you would have to be careful of name collision.